# DRF list endoint returns 404 while there are objects present in db

Tags: python, django, http, django-rest-framework

There's some problem when I'm trying to retrieve a list of objects.
Here is my code (I've reduced it for simplicity)

```py
# Models.py
class TournamentType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

```py
# Serializers.py
class TournamentTypeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.TournamentType
        fields = ('id', 'name')
```

```py
# Views.py
class TournamentTypeViewSet(ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = TournamentType.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.TournamentTypeSerializer
```

```py
# Urls.py
if settings.DEBUG:
    router = DefaultRouter()
else:
    router = SimpleRouter()

router.register("tournament_types", views.TournamentTypeViewSet)

app_name = "tournaments"
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

In Swagger I end up seeing 2 request types:

```
http://localhost:8000/api/tournaments/tournament_types/{id}
http://localhost:8000/api/tournaments/tournament_types/
```

First one (with ID) returns object as expected.
But the second one, which is supposed to return a list, returns a 404 response.

I've tried specifying a request type by adding this to the view:

```py
def list(self, request):
    queryset = TournamentType.objects.all()
    serializer = serializers.TournamentTypeSerializer(queryset, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

But result is still the same.

What am I missing? I've checked all the docs, and everything seems to be in place.

## UPDATE

I've managed to make a method that returns the list of objects but the endpoint looks odd and it's definitely a crutch rather than a proper solution:

```py
# Views.py
class TournamentTypeViewSet(ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = TournamentType.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.TournamentTypeSerializer

    @swagger_auto_schema(method="get")
    @action(detail=True, methods=["get"])
    def tt(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = TournamentType.objects.all()
        serializer = serializers.TournamentTypeSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

`/api/tournaments/tournament-types/{id}/tt/`
It returns the list but it requires some input to work, it can be anything,
it doesn't seem to check that `id` argument.

If I send a request to `/api/tournaments/tournament-types/tt/`, it returns same 404 response, not an error.

Comment: How you define route for this endpoint?

Comment: Show your urls.py

Comment: Updated the post with `Urls.py` @shafik, @JPG

Comment: I've also checked replies in Postman, just to be sure, Same result.

Comment: Can you just try by removing last `/`

Comment: @shafik, same result. In fact, that's the address that Swagger shows me and if I remove the ending "/", it corrects me anyway.

Comment: When adding my viewset urls I use the following: ` urlpatterns =  [path("", include(router.urls))]. Looking at your urls it looks as if you are assigning the urlpatterns to the router object whereas urls should be a list of urls.

Comment: Also, a great package is django-extensions. It will give you an extra option you can use with manage.py to show all your urls. `manage.py show_urls`

Comment: @anowlinorbit, thanks, it doesn't seem to have any effect, works in the same way it used to.

Comment: I've also installed `django-extensions` and it gives me predictable results:

`/api/tournaments/tournament_types/      core.tournament.views.TournamentTypeViewSet     api:tournaments:tournamenttype-list
/api/tournaments/tournament_types/<pk>/ core.tournament.views.TournamentTypeViewSet     api:tournaments:tournamenttype-detail`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the way to fix it. The problem was in routes. Previously my `tournaments/urls.py` looked like this:

```py
router = DefaultRouter()

router.register("tournament-types", TournamentTypeViewSet)

app_name = "tournaments"
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

And then it was passed on to the main `router.py`.
But when I put it directly into the main file, it started working:

```py
router = DefaultRouter()

router.register("tournament-types", TournamentTypeViewSet)

app_name = "app_name"
urlpatterns = [path("tournaments/", include('core.tournament.urls'))]
urlpatterns += router.urls
```

Not sure why the first version doesn't work though.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, it worked for me.

I think you're doing something wrong in urls.py of the main project folder or you've changed something in settings.py

Restart your IDE and try running again. Make sure to check the urls.py of main project folder.

Comment: My main `url.py` looks like this:
`path("api/", include("config.api_router"))`. And `api_router`, which it is referencing looks like this: 
`app_name = "api" / urlpatterns = [path("tournaments/", include('core.tournament.urls'))] / urlpatterns += router.urls`. It includes some other endpoints that work fine. Thanks for confirming I'm not missing anything.

Comment: In which directory you've added                                                                                       
 `if settings.DEBUG:
    router = DefaultRouter()
else:
    router = SimpleRouter()

router.register("tournament_types", views.TournamentTypeViewSet)

app_name = "tournaments"
urlpatterns = router.urls`

Comment: .tournaments.urls.py